# How to use ActionFilter once to perform on all controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, action-filter

I have a situation where I need one Filter to be executed before every api call but in dot net you have to write that filter above every controller.
[ActionFilterName].

I have so many controllers written and writing this tag above every controller is kind of hectic.
Is there any way that this filter will be called before every controller execution without writing it above every controller.
Like we get in Java's Spring boot there we don't need to write our filter annotation above every controller it just gets executed before API call.

I font know if this question is similar to already asked question if yes please tell me guys I'm new here.

Comment: What you want is called global filter (that is not even mentioned in the first answer below). That's terrible. We don't simply need the stuff, we need its (technical) name as well so that we can talk or discuss about it, find more about it ... Really when you learned about filters in asp.net core, you should have known about this term. Always try to read the documentation first (I know it's very long and time consuming but it's worthy) before using it.

Comment: I get your point but the thing is I'm Java developer and I was told to do this just for one day so I gathered this much info and somehow managed to ask the question which is almost understandable @Hopeless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For asp.net core 2.x,try this:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new CustomActionFilter());  
    //or 
    //options.Filters.Add(typeof(CustomActionFilter));      
}).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#filter-scopes-and-order-of-execution-1

For asp.net core 3.x,try this:

```
services.AddControllers(config =>
{
    config.Filters.Add(new CustomActionFilter());
});
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#filter-scopes-and-order-of-execution